# jQuery ajax request in wordpress

Tags: jquery, ajax, wordpress

```
jQuery('.tm-floating-box').on('click', '.createpdfdata', function () {
        var tottal_data = jQuery('.tm-pdf-data .total_tm_data').val();
        var countdata;
        var i;
        var total_box_data = {};
        total_box_data.product = [];
        total_box_data.action_data = [];
        total_box_data.product_data = [];
        //total_box_data.product.push({ '1': { 'data': 'data1' } });
        if (tottal_data > 0) {
            for (countdata = 0; countdata < tottal_data; countdata++) {
                if (jQuery("#total_fb_" + countdata + "_title").val() && jQuery("#total_fb_" + countdata + "_price").val() && jQuery("#total_fb_" + countdata + "_value").val()) {
                    var title = jQuery("#total_fb_" + countdata + "_title").val();
                    var price = jQuery("#total_fb_" + countdata + "_price").val();
                    var valedata = jQuery("#total_fb_" + countdata + "_value").val();

                    var totlacountindex = countdata;
                    total_box_data.product.push({ totlacountindex: { 'title': title , 'price': price ,'valuedata': valedata } });


                }


            }
            var product_title = jQuery(".product_title").text();
            var product_price = jQuery(".woocommerce-Price-amount").text();
            var product_description = jQuery(".product_data_short_description").val();
            total_box_data.product_data.push({ 'product_details': { 'product_title': product_title, 'product_price': product_price, 'product_description': product_description } });
            total_box_data.action_data.push({ 'product_action': 'product_pdf_data' });
            jQuery.ajax({
                url: site_params.ajaxurl,
                type: "POST",
                data: JSON.stringify(total_box_data),
                dataType: 'json',
                async: false,
                cache: false,
                contentType: false,
                processData: false,
                success: function(response) {



                     if(response.status == 'failure')
                     {

                        jQuery('.digicore_form_registration-result').html('<div class="alert alert-danger">' + response.error_message + '</div>');

                     }
                     else
                     {
                        jQuery('.digicore_form_registration-result').html('<div class="alert alert-success alert-dismissible">' + response.success_msg + '</div>'); 


                     }

                }
            });
```

Comment: I have give solution not ask question

Answer (score 1):

As I saw you gave solution not asked question but here is my solution regarding ajax request in wp.
Just pass action into data of ajax call. 
like `action='createpdfrequest'.`
and pass `<?php echo admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' )?>` into url of ajax.

In your function.php file:
Use add_action hook like,

```
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_createpdfrequest', 'createpdfrequest' );
add_action( 'wp_ajax_createpdfrequest', 'createpdfrequest' ); 


function post_love_add_love() {
 // do stuff here
}
```

In above example, use your action (which you passed into ajax call) with wp_ajax_nopriv_ and wp_ajax_ hooks. 'createpdfrequest' this is the callback function to write the code.

Hope this will help you and this is what you were looking for. Thanks.